# How to collect products of DiracDelta functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching

After taking a FourierTransform, I have the following expression containing multidimensional products of delta functions (what I am actually working with is far longer than this excerpt):

```
myexpr = -I B z0 DiracDelta[\[Pi] - 2 \[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Pi] - 2 \[Xi]] +
   2 I G z0 DiracDelta[\[Pi] - 2 \[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Pi] - 2 \[Xi]] -
   1/4 I B z1 DiracDelta[3 \[Pi] - 2 \[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Pi] - 2 \[Xi]] +
   1/2 I G z1 DiracDelta[3 \[Pi] - 2 \[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Pi] - 2 \[Xi]] -
   (1/8 + I/8) B z1 DiracDelta[\[Eta]] DiracDelta[3 \[Pi] - 2 \[Xi]] -
   (1/8 + I/8) R z1 DiracDelta[\[Eta]] DiracDelta[3 \[Pi] - 2 \[Xi]] +
   (1/8 + I/8) B z2 DiracDelta[\[Eta]] DiracDelta[3 \[Pi] - 2 \[Xi]] -
   (1/8 + I/8) R z2 DiracDelta[\[Eta]] DiracDelta[3 \[Pi] - 2 \[Xi]] -
   (1/8 + I/8) B z1 DiracDelta[\[Pi] -
   2 \[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Pi] - \[Xi]] +
   (1/8 - I/8) R z1 DiracDelta[\[Pi] + 2 \[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Pi] - \[Xi]] -
   1/8 B z1 DiracDelta[\[Pi] - \[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Xi]] +
   1/2 B z0 DiracDelta[\[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Xi]] +
   G z0 DiracDelta[\[Eta]] DiracDelta[\[Xi]];
```

I would like to Use `Collect` to bring together terms that share the same 2D `DiracDelta`, but have not been able to find a pattern that allows this to work. For a simple polynomial expression, we can use something like

```
Collect[(1 + a + x)^4, x]
```

to gather together terms sharing powers of x. But how can we do this for a function like `DiracDelta`? It is easy to convert the products of `DiracDelta` into multidimensional functions using

```
mynewexpr = myexpr /. {DiracDelta[p_] DiracDelta[q_] :> DiracDelta[p, q]}
```

but this doesn't seem to help, as far as collecting terms goes.

Comment: Doesn't quite work, but what about `Collect[myexpr,_DiracDelta]` as a starting point?

Comment: It should be noticed that, for example, $\delta (\pi -2 \eta ) \delta (\pi -2 \xi ) $ is not a usual product, but a tensor product (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) for info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy your code, the +- operators are read as signs producing single line output. To have a sum, the signs have to be positioned at the end of the lines.

```
   products = 
     Cases[Flatten[Outer[(#1*#2 &), #, #]] &[
        Cases[myexpr // Expand , _DiracDelta, \[Infinity]] ] // Union, 
             Except[Power[_, 2]]]

    Collect[myexpr, products]
```

$$\delta (\eta ) \delta (\xi ) \left(\frac{B \text{z0}}{2}+G \text{z0}\right)+\delta (\pi -2 \eta ) \delta (\pi -2 \xi ) (2 i G \text{z0}-i B \text{z0})$$
$$+\delta (3 \pi -2 \eta ) \delta (\pi -2 \xi ) \left(\frac{i G \text{z1}}{2}-\frac{i B \text{z1}}{4}\right)$$
$$+\delta (\eta ) \delta (3 \pi -2 \xi )\left(\left(-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{i}{8}\right) B \text{z1}+
 \left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{i}{8}\right) B \text{z2}-\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{i}{8}\right) R \text{z1}-\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{i}{8}\right) R \text{z2}\right)$$
$$-\left(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{i}{8}\right) B \text{z1} \delta (\pi -2 \eta ) \delta (\pi -\xi )-\frac{1}{8} B \text{z1} \delta (\pi -\eta ) \delta (\xi )+\left(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{i}{8}\right) R \text{z1} \delta (2 \eta +\pi ) \delta (\pi -\xi )$$

Comment: That worked - thanks! And I have modified the code in my question to move the signs to the right hand side, following your comment.